# PHPMailer - this stream does not support SSL/crypto

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to get PHPMailer working and keep getting this error:

```
PHP Warning:  stream_socket_enable_crypto(): this stream does not support SSL/crypto in /usr/share/php5/class.smtp.php on line 274
```

I've seen a few posts where people have fixed the problem by uncommenting this:
    extension=php_openssl.dll

which I have done - and restarted apache.

Any ideas?

Here is the php example code I am using:

Running php 5.3.17 and Apache 2.2.22 on OpenSuse 12.3

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "mail.yourdomain.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 1;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
// 1 = errors and messages
// 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 // sets the prefix to the servier
$mail->Host       = "smtp.gmail.com";      // sets GMAIL as the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 587;                   // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "my email address";  // GMAIL username
$mail->Password   = "my password";            // GMAIL password

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via smtp (Gmail), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);
$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

if(!$mail->Send()) {
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved.

On opensuse I had to install php5-openssl

Restarted apache - all working 100% now.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
it is tested

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>PHPMailer - SMTP basic test with authentication</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php


    error_reporting(E_STRICT);

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');

    require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
    //include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

    $mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
    $mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    $mail->Port = 465; // or 587
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->Username = "***";
    $mail->Password = "***";
    $mail->SetFrom("dad");
    $mail->Subject = "Test";
    $mail->Body = "hello";
    $mail->AddAddress("janakprajapati90@gmail.com");
     if(!$mail->Send())
        {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        }
        else
        {
        echo "Message has been sent";
        }

    ?>

    </body>
    </html>
```